# How to check what month it is? Python

Tags: python, calendar

I am writing a code which assigns certain data to different seasons. What I want is for the program to print the various data depending on what month it currently is.

```
Autumn = 'September'
Autumn = 'October'
Autumn = 'November'
Autumn = 'December'
Autumn = 'January' #(The start Jan 01)
Spring = 'January' #(Jan 02 onwards)
Spring = 'February'
Spring = 'March'
Spring = 'April' #(The start April 04)
Summer = 'April' #(April 05 onwards)
Summer = 'May'
Summer = 'June'
Summer = 'July'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `strftime()` function from the `time` module. This will store the current month in a variable called `current_month`.

```
from time import strftime
current_month = strftime('%B')
```

If you want to get the current season from this, try this function:

```
def get_season(month):
    seasons = {
    'Autumn': ['September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January'],
    'Spring': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    'Summer': ['April', 'May', 'June', 'July']
    }

    for season in seasons:
        if month in seasons[season]:
            return season
    return 'Invalid input month'
```

Currently, this will not solve the date conflicts that you specified, as any day in January will return `'Autumn'`, and any day in April will get you `'Spring'`.

Answer (score 7):

```
time.strftime("%b")
```

will tell you the current month (abbreviation)

```
time.strftime("%m")
```

will give you the numeric month (ie 1 = Jan / 12 = Dec)

(or even better)

```
datetime.datetime.now().month
```

as that will give you an actual integer instead of a string (be for-warned though January is 0)

Comment: For the numeric month, I'd use `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now().month`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().month  # As a number
4
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%B")  # As a name
'April'
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%b")  # As an abbreviated name
'Apr'
>>>
```

Comment: `.strftime` is also a method on `datetime` objects, so you'd normally write that as `datetime.now().strftime('%b')`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser - Right, my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

whit `import datetime`
you can use `datetime.date.today()`
and return Current date or datetime

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue of finding a month.